# How to encrypt folder files using zip.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption, zip, temporary-files

Example -path1 -  desktop/file_source
Path2 - desktop/e_data_source.
How can we encrypt files from desktop/file_source to desktope_data_source path using zip.exe in cmd.
Could you please help me.? Is it possible to do then what is process.?

Comment: Windows does not include a `zip.exe` so you need to tell use which version of `zip.exe` you use, so where did you download it?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. It's possible. Just try this
go to the file you want to encyrpt <cd desktop/file_source>

Use zip.exe to create an encrypted zip file:
<zip.exe -r -e -P your_password desktop/e_data_source/encrypted.zip .>
"remember to replace  your_password with the password you want to use for encryption"

Move the encrypted zip file to the desired location:
move encrypted.zip ../e_data_source/

This should create an encrypted zip file named encrypted.zip containing all the -
files and subdirectories from desktop/file_source and move it to desktop/e_data_source.

Comment: Zip error : invalid command arguments ( encryption not supported)